# Accessing xampp - dns error

Tags: php, dns, xampp

I recently installed xampp and i am trying to access xampp/index.php but it gives me an error about the DNS:

"The server at xampp can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network."
Error code: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I can't figure out why is this happening. I don't understand these concepts.... I would really appreciate some help. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

DNS is the system which converts human friendly names (like `stackoverflow.com`) into numeric network addresses.

You need to access `http://FOO/index.php` where `FOO` is the name of the computer the web server is running on (not the name of the bundle of software the web server came with).

If you are running the browser and server on the same machine, this will usually be `localhost`.

Comment: Thank you! "problem" solved! I'd vote you up, but i don't have points left.

Comment: Since you seem to be new here, you might find it useful to read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).